# Integration os phonegap in xcode 4.2 IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

can i integrate phonegap in XCode 4.2.

can any one please give me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obv u can. just install phonegap from here http://phonegap.com/  and then u can create [rojects from xcode